# is `libc` and `crt1.o` statically or dynamically linked?

Tags: c, linker, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I'm really just trying to get my head around static and dynamic linking.

When I invoke a compilation driver like `unix> gcc myfile.c`, `crt1.o` and `libc.a` (or `libc.dylib`)  are linked to produce the executable by `ld`. I want to guess that `crt.o` is linked statically and the standard C lib is linked dynamically. Yes?

Thanks for help. I think I may need a new text on linking :S
`

Comment: `crt.o`, or `crt1.o`, is not a library. It's just an object file. It's very small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> want to guess that crt.o is linked statically and the standard C lib is linked dynamically. Yes?

No.

Not exactly.

`crt0.o` and its family (`bundle1.o`, `dylib1.o`, etc.) are object files, not libraries, they are not linked at all. `libc.a` is a static library so when you link against it, it will be linked statically (i. e. the object files it contains will be essentially copied to your executable). Static libraries aren't, however, linked themselves either. `libc.dylib` is a dynamically linked library - guess how it is linked when you use it (dynamically, of course, and in this case, the library **itself** is a linked, proper executable file).

Comment: Why do you say object files aren't linked in?

Comment: @Barmar It's not that they aren't linked in to your executable - they aren't *linked* (themselves). They are the result of compilation.

Comment: @Barmar I've answered that too.

Comment: @H2CO3 ya, I got that `lib.a` and `lib.dylib` would be statically/dynamically linked respectively. My question was what is the default when I call the `gcc` driver. Also, what do you mean my object files not linked in? `crt1.o` must be linked in somehow?

Comment: @ZacharyO'Keefe To 1: AFAIK on most modern systems dynamic linkage is the default. To 2: read my explanation 2 comments above.

Comment: gcc typically dynamically links on platforms that support dynamic linking. say Linux, or Darwin (also Solaris, HPUX, *BSD etc.) normal installations would use dynamic linking. A long time ago you had to request dynamic linking that was when most of the objects / libs didn't have  Position Independent Code (PIC) version of the functions.   (you might see a -fPIC flag in gcc) nowadays it's the default so dynamic linkage can be assumed.

Comment: @AhmedMasud thank you for that response. Ya I've seen `-fPIC`. What about `crt1.o` though? Where is that guy going?

Comment: @ZacharyO'Keefe Into your executable.